# JPA @ManyToMany relationship saved on only one side when database is reloaded

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, derby

I'm using JPA for an application with EclipseLink and Apache Derby.  I have two Entities in a @ManyToMany relationship:

```
@Entity
class HIT<TaskType> {
   ...
   @ManyToMany(targetEntity=Task.class, mappedBy="hits")
   protected List<TaskType> tasks = Lists.newArrayList();
}

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
abstract class Task {
    ...
    @ManyToMany(targetEntity=HIT.class)
    protected List<HIT<?>> hits = Lists.newArrayList();
}
```

I first create two tasks of an entity `EventPresenceTask`, a subclass of `Task`, and persist them.  Later, I query the EntityManager to recover those tasks and use them to create a instance of `EventPresenceHIT`, a subtype of `HIT`.  When the HIT is created, it adds both tasks to its `tasks` list and adds itself to the `hits` list of each task.  It is then persisted.

After creating the objects, I check everything by first querying the `EntityManager` for all `HIT`s and printing them, then querying the `EntityManager` for all `Task`s and printing those.  I get:

```
EventPresenceHIT{...  #tasks=2}
EventPresenceTask{... # hits=1}
EventPresenceTask{... # hits=1}
```

as expected.  But if I close the application and reload the database, I get:

```
EventPresenceHIT{... #tasks=0}
EventPresenceTask{... #hits=1}
EventPresenceTask{... #hits=1}
```

Since everything appears to be correct in new queries to the `EntityManager` in the initial run of the program, I was worried that the `EntityManger` wasn't flushing to the database (since the program is terminated by Ctrl-C), so I put `entityManager.close()` in a shutdown hook to be extra safe, but it hasn't helped.

**Updated**: To make clear that what are being persisted and related are instances of subclasses of `HIT` and `Task` which are themselves entities.

Comment: Why do you have `@ManyToMany(targetEntity=BBNHIT.class)` and not simply `@ManyToMany` or `@ManyToMany(targetEntity=HIT.class)`?

Comment: @JBNizet: Sorry, that was a typo.  It should be simply `HIT.class`. I've updated the question. If I remove the `targetEntity` attribute, database creation crashes with a `NullPointerException` in EclipseLink code. I think it may be due to `HIT` being a generic class, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Turn on eclipselink logging to see the SQL used to read in the HIT and associated Tasks when you access the tasks collection http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Logging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly mistake - I had forgotten to annotate an inheritance strategy on the `HIT` class.  After I did so, DB creation crashed with exceptions. However, switched to the `JOINED` inheritance strategy for both classes works.